# No me funciona mi excepcion creada por mi mismo java poo

Tags: java, poo

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Operaciones.cargarDatosClientes();
  Operaciones.imprimirDatos();
}
```

---

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author alumno-203
 */
public class Operaciones {

    private static Cliente listaCliente[] = new Cliente[2];
    private static BufferedReader entrada = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    private static Scanner entrada1 = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void cargarDatosClientes() throws IOException {
        System.out.println("**INGRESE DATOS DEL CLIENTE**");
        for (int i = 0; i < listaCliente.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
            Cliente cliente = new Cliente();
            try {
                System.out.println("Nombre Completo");
                cliente.setNombreCompleto(entrada.readLine());
            } catch (Excepcion e) {
                e.mensajePersonalizado();
            }

            System.out.println("Nro Cuenta");
            cliente.setNumeroCuenta(entrada.readLine());
            try {
                System.out.println("Saldo inicial");
                cliente.setSaldoInicial(entrada1.nextInt());
                System.out.println("Total articulo");
                cliente.setTotalArticulos(entrada1.nextInt());
                System.out.println("Total creditos");
                cliente.setTotalCreditos(entrada1.nextInt());
                System.out.println("Limite credito");
                cliente.setLimiteCredito(entrada1.nextInt());
            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                System.err.println("Error se debe ingresar un valor numerico ");
            }

            listaCliente[i] = cliente;
        }

    }

    public static void imprimirDatos() {
        for (int i = 0; i < listaCliente.length; i++) {
            long nroSaldo = (listaCliente[i].getSaldoInicial() + listaCliente[i].getTotalArticulos()) - listaCliente[i].getTotalCreditos();
            System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
            if (nroSaldo > listaCliente[i].getLimiteCredito()) {
                System.err.println("El cliente " + listaCliente[i].getNombreCompleto() + " se excedio el límite de credito ");
                System.out.println("");
            } else {
                System.out.printf("El cliente " + listaCliente[i].getNombreCompleto() + " no se excedio al límite de credito");
                System.out.println("");
            }

        }
    }
}
----------------------------------------------------
public class Excepcion extends NumberFormatException {

    public Excepcion() {

        super();
    }

    public Excepcion(String string) {
        super(string);
    }

    public void mensajePersonalizado() {

        System.err.println("Error: Dato ingreso incorrecto, ingrese solo caracteres.");
    }
}
```

---

No se que porque no funciona.. Tengo que hacer de esta forma para una tarea de la universidad.

Comment: Y que te ocurre exactamente, porque me parece que en esta linea (`cliente.setNombreCompleto(entrada.readLine())`) nunca lanza ese tipo de excepción.

Comment: Necesito que ingrese solo letras, no numeros, asi ingresaria un nombre valido. Si llegara a poner un numero, se deberia activar la excepcion pero no funciona.

Comment: La excepción que estás capturando tiene que ser lanzada por algún método. Por lo que comentas, el método `setNombreCompleto()` debería ser quien la lance, luego de validar el valor del parámetro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes añadir un control en el método setNombreCompleto que te valide si la cadena recibida como parámetro contiene números o no. Yo lo haría así (usando expresiones regulares):

```
public void setNombreCompleto(String valor) throws Excepcion {
    //Pattern y Matcher pertenecen a java.util.regex
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+"); //Expresión regular para buscar cualquier secuencia de números
    Matcher m = p.matcher(valor);
    if (m.matches()) {
        throw new Excepcion("El nombre introducido no es válido, contiene números");
    } 
}
```

Obviamente, ese pattern y ese matcher podrían estar declarados como variables globales estáticas finales de la clase Cliente, ya que no dejan de ser constantes.

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Imagino que cliente tiene el campo `nombre` de tipo `String`.

y la clase `Excepcion` hereda de `NumberFormatException`

La clase `NumberFormatException` captura las excepciones cuando el campo que estás intentando ingresar es de tipo Number (long, float, int, double, etc) y no se logra formatear o castear cuando lees el String.

como probar la excepción:

pide también el número de cuenta dentro del try. y rectifica:

```
try {
      System.out.println("Nombre Completo");
      cliente.setNombreCompleto(entrada.readLine());

      System.out.println("Ingrese el Nro Cuenta");
      cliente.setNumeroCuenta(entrada.readLine());
} catch (Excepcion e) {
      e.mensajePersonalizado();
}
```

OJO!!! el tipo de formato del atributo `numeroCuenta` debe estar en un tipo de dato numérico para que la función funcione, de esta manera si ingresas un texto como :

```
> 'Ingrese el Nro de cuanta': 
> hola mundo
```

Vas a generar la excepción que buscas

Comment: Debe estar en string porque el numero de cuenta puede ser asi: 454Ag46... Segun el ejercicio. Lo que busco es que se active la excepcion cuando ingresa un numero en el campo Nombre. Solo ahi..

Comment: Lo siento amigo, java no tiene ese tipo de excepciones, ahí debes hacer una validación, es decir, convertir el String a un Char[] y recorrer el vector de la cadena letra por letra para verificar si se ingresó un número.

Comment: Ya veo, en ese caso.